# Plugins folder causing issues after migration

Tags: php, wordpress, migration, database-migration, php-ini

I copied the files and the database to my test server and replaced the url of the live site by the one of the test site in wp_options. I moved sites this way many times in the past but today when I try to access the test site I get a long list of errors:

> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   'core/fields/tab.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php')
>   in /xxx/yyy/plugins/zzz/xxx.php on line 000

The files are all there (in the plugins folder).
The site loads if I move the plugins out of the plugins folder.
Any idea why this is happening and how to fix this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: It seems like this just happens with some plugins... A simple fix was to delete the plugin causing the error and reinstall it. I'm just wondering if there's another way to handle this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your new host uses a different install path for Php and Pear than the original server.

The plugin seems to require a file that is not on the default include path on the new server.